# Starting a GUI process from a Python Windows Service

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-services

I am creating Windows service class in Python that will eventually display a Window when certain conditions are met. Since (as I understand it) services cannot have GUIs, I'm trying to start up a GUI in a seperate process (using `subprocess.Popen`) when the conditions are right. This isn't working, presumably because the child process has the same privileges as the service.

So how do I start a process from a Python Windows Service that has the ability to display GUIs on the screen?

Comment: Reworked question and removed irrelevant code to be less misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your Service the `Allow service to interact with desktop` permission it will be able to create windows without the need to launch a subprocess.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. How can you `Allow service to interact with desktop`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204082/2946116), you may have to (eventually) transition to a client-server model since Windows Vista and later [no longer support direct interaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with users.