# wxPython: How to put a textbox control on the popup menu

Tags: python, wxpython

I can implement a trayicon with popup menu following the code of this topic:
[Quick and easy: trayicon with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python)

thanks for the guys in that topic very much and now I have another question here:

**Could I add a textbox control in the menu to let the user to input something?**

What I want is a menu with textbox control:

In the official doc and demo of wxPython we can see the text control added to the menubar, but not the popup menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it? I can't think of any limitations on the PopupMenu that would prevent you from doing it. If it doesn't work, try using FlatMenu. That widget is pure Python and can probably be hacked to support it if it doesn't already.