# How can I develop Windows PC background tray apps using Python?

Tags: python, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick and easy: trayicon with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python)

Is there a Python API for Windows PC OS such as vista or windows 7?

I want to design a tiny application, which can look for actively selected item in any folder, and have a small background window to display some message.

Comment: Thanks. But I am also asking for a small background window, kind of notification window, without any controls.

Comment: wxPython easily provides for that with its wxDialog...I have worked extensively with wxPython and I find it very easy to use for most common UI task stuff