# Windows: How to Run any python application silently in taskbar during idle state

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick and easy: trayicon with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python)

Is there a way with python to run an python based application silently In taskbar during  its Idle state

Comment: What does that mean? "silently in taskbar", "idle state". Please elaborate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean how to minimize any python based applications to system tray in Windows os

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Details required!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan WxPython any Python 2.7

Comment: Google searches for wxpython and tray icon or notification icon will yield a gazillion hits that tell you how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You could start your application normally and then hide it through pywin32 magic.

Alternatively you could make your program a service, I'm no sure how that's done though.