# Python 3 and WX to create System Tray Icon

Tags: wxpython, python-3.6

I'm having some trouble getting this code [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python) running on Python3 with WX. I made some edits to the code but I'm still getting this error. What am I missing? This is Python 3.6 with the Project Phoenix WX module on Windows7. Pretty frustrated, since I've tried about 4 different test code samples to implement a systray Icon and none of them work.

```
import wx.adv

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'System Tray Demo'
TRAY_ICON = 'icon.png'

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
menu.AppendItem(item)
return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

def CreatePopupMenu(self):
    menu = wx.Menu()
    create_menu_item(menu, 'Say Hello', self.on_hello)
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
    return menu

def set_icon(self, path):
    icon = wx.Icon(wx.Bitmap(path))
    self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

def on_left_down(self, event):
    print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

def on_hello(self, event):
    print ('Hello, world!')

def on_exit(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
    self.frame.Close()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still using wxpython Classic, so I can't test this.
wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN is the normal event but you are importing `TaskBarIcon` from `wx.adv`, so I assume that you should use `wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN`

Comment: Gah, that was it! I swear I had tried that, must of had something else messed up at the time aswell. Also, for future reference, "AppendItem" needs to change to "Append". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Working Code, Python 3.9

```
import wx.adv

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'System Tray Demo'
TRAY_ICON = 'off.png'

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.AppendItem(item)
    return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame

        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        icon = wx.Icon(wx.Bitmap(TRAY_ICON, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))

        self.SetIcon(icon,TRAY_TOOLTIP)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Say Hello', self.on_hello)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def set_icon(self, path):
        icon = wx.Icon(wx.Bitmap(path))
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

    def on_hello(self, event):
        print ('Hello, world!')

    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```