# Python 3 Wx Change tray icon

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, system-tray

I'm using WxPython (phoenix new version) to have an icon on the tray bar while the programs runs, but I would some events to change the icon used.

I found this great example to get things started: [Quick and easy: trayicon with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python)

But it doesn't have the example to cycle through icons.

Just after the imports it has this line:

```
TRAY_ICON = 'icon.png'
```

And I've tried to use that as sort of a variable, and adding the following line to an event (it has some mock events like hellow world on a right click

```
TRAY_ICON = 'icon2.png'
```

but it didn't work =//

I only found examples in c, and one in python but using a very complex win32 alternative that I can't figure out

Comment: The line from the linked answer that's relevant is `self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)`.  You need to call this method on your class to update the display.  It may also require a call to `.Refresh()` - it's been a long time since I used wx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should provide you with enough to solve your problem.

```
import wx
import wx.adv

ICON = 'toggle1.png'
ICONS = ["toggle1.png", "toggle2.png"]

X=[1,0]

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        self.toggle = 0
        wx.adv.TaskBarIcon.__init__(self)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnToggle)
        self.OnSetIcon(ICON)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        togglem = wx.MenuItem(menu, wx.NewId(), 'Toggle Icon')
        menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnToggle, id=togglem.GetId())
        menu.Append(togglem)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        flashm = wx.MenuItem(menu, wx.NewId(), 'Flash Icon')
        menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnTimer, id=flashm.GetId())
        menu.Append(flashm)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        quitm = wx.MenuItem(menu, wx.NewId(), 'Quit')
        menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=quitm.GetId())
        menu.Append(quitm)
        return menu

    def OnSetIcon(self, path):
        icon = wx.Icon(path)
        self.SetIcon(icon, path)

    def OnToggle(self, event):
        self.toggle=X[self.toggle]
        use_icon = ICONS[self.toggle]
        self.OnSetIcon(use_icon)

    def OnTimer(self,event):
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnInUseTimer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    def OnInUseTimer(self,event):
        self.OnToggle(None)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.RemoveIcon()
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame=wx.Frame(None)
    TaskBarIcon(frame)
    app.MainLoop()
```

and the images:
[image: toggle1.png] [image: toggle2.png]

In action:
[image]